# MYSQL 3 consecutive occurence of record based on year

Tags: mysql

i have two tables table1: PERIODS and table2:PROBATIONARY, im trying to get whether a student accumulated 3 consecutive ONPROBATIONARY status based on the YEAR column of PERIODS table. SO basically im just expecting a 1 or 0 output, hence if the resultset turned FALSE, i want to know if the student was onprobation from the previous semester. im basically new to mysql and i find it diffuclut to create this one in a single query any help will greatly appreciated.

```
-- PERIOD TABLE

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `period` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `year` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nstart` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `nend` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `ext` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `enrstart` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `enrend` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `enrext` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `addstart` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `addend` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `addext` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `orvalidate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `idmask` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;  

-- PERIOD VALUES

-- Dumping data for table `period`
--

INSERT INTO `period` (`id`, `code`, `name`, `year`, `term`, `nstart`, `nend`, `ext`, `enrstart`, `enrend`, `enrext`, `addstart`, `addend`, `addext`, `orvalidate`, `idmask`) VALUES
(1, '20181', 'First Semester, 2018-2019', 2018, '1', '2018-08-13', '2018-12-13', '2019-05-01', '2018-07-13', '2018-09-13', '2019-03-29', '2018-08-13', '2018-09-13', '2019-03-29', '2018-12-13', '181'),
(2, '20182', 'Second Semester, 2018-2019', 2018, '2', '2019-01-14', '2019-05-14', '2019-05-14', '2018-12-14', '2019-02-14', '2019-05-27', '2019-01-14', '2019-02-14', '2019-05-27', '2019-05-14', '182'),
(3, '20171', 'First Semester, 2017-2018', 2017, '1', '2017-08-14', '2017-12-14', '2017-12-14', '2017-07-14', '2017-09-14', '2017-09-14', '2017-08-14', '2017-09-14', '2017-09-14', '2017-12-14', '171'),
(4, '20172', 'Second Semester, 2017-2018', 2017, '2', '2017-01-09', '2017-05-09', '2017-05-09', '2016-12-09', '2017-02-09', '2017-02-09', '2017-01-09', '2017-02-09', '2017-02-09', '2017-05-09', '172'),
(5, '20173', 'Short Term 2017', 2017, '3', '2017-06-05', '2017-08-05', '2017-08-05', '2017-05-05', '2017-07-05', '2017-07-05', '2017-06-05', '2017-07-05', '2017-07-05', '2017-08-05', '173');

-- PROBATIONARY TABLE

-- Table structure for table `probationary`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `probationary` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `period` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `totalunits` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `passedunits` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `onprob` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

-- PROBATIONARY VALUES

INSERT INTO `probationary` (`id`, `student`, `period`, `totalunits`, `passedunits`, `onprob`) VALUES
(1, 753, 1, '29', '12', 1),
(2, 753, 3, '29', '12', 1),
(3, 753, 4, '29', '12', 1);
```

Comment: Please add the desired results, matching the data in your INSERT statements. Your "*based on the YEAR column*" is not clear to me, considering that your periods are semesters and not full years.

Comment: Luckily, there is only one student

Comment: i only want to know if the student accumulated 3 consecutive semester that is onprob = 1, the semester was arrange by year, if you can see 20171,20172,20173,20181,20182. so if my current semester is 20182 i want to know if the student is onprob = 1 in semester 20181,20173,20172

Comment: Are the `id` column in both tables the same thing? Edited: No, I don't think so. What would be the column that have relation between both tables?

Comment: they are related period.id = probationary.period

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways I can think of but lets try one thing first and see if the result is what you aim for:

`SELECT P.id,P.Code,P.Name,P.Year,A.Student "20182", B.Student "20181", C.Student "20173", D.Student "20172", E.Student "20171" FROM period P LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM probationary a JOIN period b ON a.period=b.id WHERE a.onprob=1 AND b.code="20182") A ON P.code=A.code LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM probationary a JOIN period b ON a.period=b.id WHERE a.onprob=1 AND b.code="20181") B ON P.code=B.code LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM probationary a JOIN period b ON a.period=b.id WHERE a.onprob=1 AND b.code="20173") C ON P.code=C.code LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM probationary a JOIN period b ON a.period=b.id WHERE a.onprob=1 AND b.code="20172") D ON P.code=D.code LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM probationary a JOIN period b ON a.period=b.id WHERE a.onprob=1 AND b.code="20171") E ON P.code=E.code;`

On this you will see result as attached:
[image: example result]

Note that in the `probationary` table I added another student `754` just for the purpose to see how the result will show if there's more than one student.

Comment: Here's SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c464fe/6 . I've added `IFNULL` to make the result look cleaner.

Comment: the result set you are showing means that STUDENT 753 did not accumulated 3 consecutive probationary from previous periods NOR the STUDENT 754. i only want to know whether the student accumulated such probationary status

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Let me edit my answer

Comment: INSERT INTO `probationary` (`id`, `student`, `period`, `totalunits`, `passedunits`, `onprob`) VALUES
(1, 753, 1, '29', '12', 1),
(2, 753, 3, '29', '12', 1),
(3, 753, 4, '29', '12', 1),
(4, 754, 1, '30', '10', 1),
(5, 754, 5, '30', '10', 1),
(6, 754, 4, '30', '10', 1); if this would be the values of the table probationary STUDENT 753 will be FALSE and 754 will be TRUE

Comment: Ok, it took me a while to get what you mean but I think I can understand. Let me work on it a bit.

Comment: @Raymond , looks like this is beyond whatever I have worked with before. I never thought that it's something that is hard to do. I think this will take me a while to figure out as well.. I hope someone can give you an answer soon

Comment: yeahh it is somewhat complex and in my level of knowledge in mysql im really having a hard time, just to clear things a little bit, If i select a certain PERIOD, it will check the last 3 record before the selected PERIOD if the student was on probationary consecutively. it will just return TRUE or FALSE

Comment: I get what you mean. However, in my current testing, I only come as far as showing the consecutive in detail and I can't seem to figure out how to directly detect whether the occurrences happen consecutively or not from the query itself. I tried using `COUNT(*)` but that won't work. I have thought of applying mathematical formula into the query but it won't be efficient and I'm afraid the query lines will be too long.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will give you the results you want. It generates a list of the 3 prior semesters to the "active" semester (set in the subquery that generates that derived table), which is then `JOIN`ed to the `period` and `probationary` table to find all students on probation in one of those semesters. Then we count the number of `1` values of `onprob`, and if it is 3, that student must have been on probation for all 3 of the prior semesters:

```
SELECT pr.student,
       SUM(pr.onprob) AS onprob
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT code
      FROM period
      WHERE code < 20182
      ORDER BY code DESC
      LIMIT 3) l3 
JOIN period p ON p.code = l3.code
JOIN probationary pr ON pr.period = p.id
GROUP BY pr.student
HAVING onprob = 3
```

Output (for my demo):

```
student onprob
753     3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b8Hp3LZc1UsrR8d3iHXATX/1)

Comment: ill get back to you after i sort things out. thanks for the answer